# How to get rid of horizontal line in table when moving to the next page in Migradoc

Tags: pdf-generation, migradoc

I am still learning Migradoc and C# for that matter so sorry if my code is a little bit verbose but it seems if my table doesn't fit towards the bottom, it goes to the next page which is okay. But I also notice that it creates an extra horizontal line between the tables information and the headers (date, staff, notes, bill etc). I have tried everything from making the borders visibility to false and the whole rows visibility to false but it does not work. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Invoice]

Here is the code I have:

```
Table timeDetailTable2 = section.AddTable();
        timeDetailTable2.Rows.LeftIndent = "-1cm";
        timeDetailTable2.Borders.Width = 0.75;

        Column column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(4.75));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1.5));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3.75));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

        Row row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        Cell cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        cell6.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        cell6.MergeRight = 6;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Charge To: ADV Integrity / Error Message on Outlook   Location: NO NOT USE");
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Date");



        cell6 = row6.Cells[1];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Staff");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[2];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Notes");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[3];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Bill");

       cell6 = row6.Cells[4];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Hours");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Rate");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[6];

        cell6.AddParagraph("Ext Amt");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Top.Visible = false;
            cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
            cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        }

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();

        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        cell6.MergeRight = 6;
        cell6.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
        cell6.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("04/09/2020");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[1];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Beed, Jacob");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[2];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        paragraph = cell6.AddParagraph("Service Ticket:");
        paragraph.AddFormattedText(" 41466", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        paragraph2 = cell6.AddParagraph("Summary:");
        paragraph2.AddFormattedText(" New e-mail needed please, ASAP", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        paragraph3 = cell6.AddParagraph("");
        paragraph3.AddFormattedText("Created new email address for webinars and assigned exchange online" +
            "license. Mailbox will be available shortly.", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;



        cell6 = row6.Cells[3];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Y");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;


        cell6 = row6.Cells[4];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("0.50");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("125.00");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[6];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("$62.50");

        //adding horizontal line 
        row5 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        row5.Borders.Visible = false;


        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        }

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.MergeRight = 1;
        cell6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Subtotal: $187.50");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        }
```

I have the same code basically for the table above except I have it named timeDetailTable instead of timeDetailTable2 of type Table. How can I prevent that extra horizontal line between the header and table whenever I go to a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the line you see is the top border of the first row on the following page. Maybe this makes no sense at first glance.
Horizontal borders are the combination of the bottom border of the line above and the top border of the line below. And I assume this combination is made without respect to pagebreaks.

I'm afraid you cannot really do anything about this line appearing in that situation. But there are workarounds.

But IMHO it is odd to have the header and the spacer line at the end of the first page and the first data on the second page. This can easily be avoided by setting KeepWith for the first row of the block of rows you want to keep together.

Another option is marking the first rows (including the spacer row) as heading rows. Heading rows will be repeated whenever the table breaks to the next page. This should also prevent heading rows from appearing at the bottom of the page without any data row.

Comment: I took your advice on the second option and it works! The headers start on the next page instead of cutting it off and creating a horizontal line.